# SELECT INTO dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to SELECT INTO destination dynamically, something like this:

```
if @param = 0
   :setvar TARGETTABLE  T_FOO
else
   :setvar TARGETTABLE  T_BAR

SELECT.... INTO $(TARGETTABLE) FROM......;
```

And looks like `$(TARGETTABLE)` always resolves to "T_BAR". How to do this properly ?

(SQLServer 2005)

Comment: You are trying to set a variable conditionally in `sqlcmd` mode? [Don't think that is possible](http://www.youdidwhatwithtsql.com/ssms-sqlcmd-mode-a-half-done-job/782)

Comment: Martin: Yes, sqlcmd mode. I'm trying to avoid having 2 blocks of SELECT.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are creating a new table, I assume that there isn't any pre-existing stuff that has dependencies on the table name. Why not create the table with some temporary name and then rename it?

```
SELECT.... INTO T_TEMP FROM......;

if @param = 0
   EXEC sp_rename 'T_TEMP', 'T_FOO'  
else
   EXEC sp_rename 'T_TEMP', 'T_BAR'
```

Comment: good idea thanks ! better than going down dynamic sql or multi-select-block path

Answer (score 0):

You could either do this via dynamic SQL or by simply writing both queries.  I'd suggest the latter:

```
IF (@param = 0)
    SELECT ... INTO T_FOO FROM ...;
ELSE
    SELECT ... INTO T_BAR FROM ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT INTO` creates a table with the same schema as the table in the `FROM` clause.  In other words, something like this:

```
select *
into NewTable
from ExistingTable
```

This would create `NewTable` with the same structure and schema as `ExistingTable`.

You could do:

```
if @param = 0
begin
    select *
    into NewTable1
    from ExistingTable
end
else
begin
    select *
    into NewTable2
    from ExistingTable
end
```

Or you could do this:

```
declare @newTableName varchar(100)
declare @dynamicSql varchar(1000)

if @param = 0
    set @newTableName = 'NewTable1'
else
    set @newTableName = 'NewTable2'

set @dynamicSql = 'select * into ' + @newTableName + ' from ExistingTable'

exec(@dynamicSql)
```

Depending on how many options (i.e. how many conditional statements you need), if this is two or three, I'd go with the former.  If the new table name is a parameter to a stored proc, I'd go with dynamic SQL.

***NOTE***: in either way, the new table (the table name noted in `... INTO TableName` has to be a nonexistent table for you to not throw an error.